# Is it possible to add a jar/package to the classpath, then remove it after use? (during runtime)

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, conflict

Background: my primary objective is to spin up a thread, set a classpath for it, then after the thread dies I don't want anything to persist from the thread. Is it possible to reset the classloader after the execution of the thread so that any added URL packages are no persistent after?

I've been running the following code inside a separate thread:

```
    public static void addURL(URL url) throws Exception {
        URLClassLoader classLoader
        = (URLClassLoader) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Class clazz= URLClassLoader.class;

        // Use reflection
        Method method= clazz.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] { URL.class });
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(classLoader, new Object[] { url });
    }
```

then running a forname for the added class:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mypackage.myclass", false, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, after the thread exits, I'm expecting a classnotfoundexception outside of the thread if I rerun the forName() above, but it does not error out. Is there a way to remove the package from the parent thread's context classloader?

Comment: Why do you patch an existing ClassLoader instead of creating a child one? It's impossible to unload a class without unloading the entire ClassLoader. There is no way to reset a ClassLoader - you need to create a new one, and dispose it afterwards.

Comment: I've tried using Thread.setContextClassLoader() with a new classloader, but it always results in classnotfound when I try to initialize anything from the new classpath in a different thread.

Comment: That’s because the context class loader is entirely irrelevant for class loading. When you use `customClassLoader.loadClass("com.mypackage.myclass")` and the class truly has been loaded through it (i.e. not via a parent loader), all of its symbolic references will get resolved through the custom class loader, regardless of the thread used for executing the code.